# C++ Vector char integer value

Tags: c++, vector, integer, set

Is this a good and fast enough idea to set an integer value in to the vector (defined vData) of char?
Or should I use memcpy for such small operation?

```
) {
    int p1 = GetInt();
    int p2 = GetInt();

    if ( !d_bProtected )
    {
        d_vData.at(p2) = p1 & 0xFF;
        d_vData.at(p2+1) = (p1 >> 8) & 0xFF;
        d_vData.at(p2+2) = (p1 >> 16) & 0xFF;
        d_vData.at(p2+3) = (p1 >> 24) & 0xFF;

        //memcpy( &d_vData[p2], reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p1), sizeof(p1) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a little more context is needed here but, why are you storing `int` data in a `char` vector? Is it all `int` data?

Comment: No, it's random data. This project is an extension to some application, which allow user to choose, which type of value to set. Also I think there is no need to use loop for because it could slow down the code.

Comment: It sounds like you might be trying to implement a binary stream writer (writing arbitrary binary data to an underlying byte buffer). Does this sound accurate? How often are you going to be reading from `d_vData` as opposed to writing to it?

Comment: I hope that user could use the function with loops, like processing small images etc. I also tried it. Works, but I don't know if there is a faster idea.

Comment: The answer is to do whichever one reflects what you actually want to do. The two pieces of code do completely different things and it's not clear which of them is what you want to do. Is the data in `d_vData` required to be in some format that complies with some standard? Or is it expected to be in native byte order so that other code that expect native byte order can read it? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

Since `memcpy` is often compiler intrinsic, it is likely to give you exactly the same performance as manual byte-copying - with a benefit of not having to all those binary algebra yourself.

I vote for memcpy.

Comment: But is this safe when used with vectors?

Comment: @HM128, it is safe to be used in the scenario shown, provided you are not exceeding vector size, of course.

Answer (score 0):

A potentially nicer interface for `d_vData` would be to make it a `stringstream`  which, despite the name, acts as more of a binary stream buffer and has a nice interface for writing arbitrary binary data to an underlying buffer.

This would make your binary reading and writing entirely generic and wouldn't require you to write specialized functionality for every type you may potentially be writing to `d_vData`.

The example below shows how this is possible.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void write(stringstream& ss, const T& t)
{
    ss.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t), sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T>
void read(stringstream& ss, T& t)
{
    char d[sizeof(T)];
    ss.read(d, sizeof(d));
    t = *(reinterpret_cast<T*>(d));
}

int read_stringstream(stringstream& ss)
{
    // ensure read position is at the beginning of the stream
    ss.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);

    // extract data from a string stream
    int i;
    double d;

    read(ss, i);
    read(ss, d);

    cout << "i:" << i << ", d:" << d << endl;
}

int main()
{
    stringstream ss;

    int i = 42;
    double d = 69.0;

    write(ss, i);
    write(ss, d);

    read_stringstream(ss);
}
```

Comment: I want to add that the "potentially nicer interface" comes at the cost of performance. The OP (and everyone else) should weigh this option against their performance targets. `stringstream` is a pneumatic nail gun - great if you need one, but a bad idea if you're hanging a picture.

Comment: Strignstream is a terrible performant. It also subjects you to uncontrolled allocations.

Comment: All valid points. Was just providing the OP with alternatives to memcpy and implementing verbose custom write functions.